# How to access shares from Android device with KDEConnect using the command line

Tags: command-line, permissions, android, kde-apps, kde-connect

When devices were paired computer <-> phone using KDEConnect, is it possible to access the phone's SD card and internal storage directly from the command line?

Use case:

When devices was paired I want to automatically copy files from phone (internal memory, external sd card) with a script.
Steps:

1. Set devices as paired
2. Run script

With `kdeconnect-cli` I can get the device ID like that:

```
$ kdeconnect-cli --id-only -a 
166ec0250e88ff2b
```

But i can't access it here:

```
$ ls /run/user/1000/166ec0250e88ff2b/
ls: cannot access '/run/user/1000/166ec0250e88ff2b/': Permission denied
```

Permissions:

```
[root@host]# ls  -la /run/user/1000/
ls: cannot access '/run/user/1000/166ec0250e88ff2b': Permission denied
...
drwx------ 9 user user 380 Nov 17 11:57 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 user user 60 Nov 17 08:07 ..
d????????? ? ?         ?           ?            ? 166ec0250e88ff2b
```

How do I access the file system of internal and external storage of the phone?

```
$ ls -la /run/user/1000/166ec0250e88ff2b/storage
total 0
dr-x------ 1 user user 0 Jan  1  1970 0000-0000/
d--x------ 1 user user 0 Feb  6  1970 emulated/
d--x------ 1 user user 0 Sep  2 20:10 self/

$ ls -la /run/user/1000/166ec0250e88ff2b/storage/0000-0000/
ls: reading directory '/run/user/1000/166ec0250e88ff2b/storage/0000-0000/': Operation not permitted
total 0
```

Comment: No CLI, but at least access via GNOME Shell and Nautlius: https://github.com/andyholmes/gnome-shell-extension-gsconnect

Comment: sure i can access also with Dolphin in KDE but i want to do it from shell script

Comment: I'm sorry to say that, but this may very well just be impossible.

Answer (score 1):

**Mconnect** is a KDE Connect protocol implementation in Vala/C available via [github.com](https://github.com/bboozzoo/mconnect). It doesn't need KDE libraries and comes with a client that lets you easily share files from the command line with e.g.

```
 mconnectctl share-file /org/mconnect/device/0 /path/to/file
```

See the linked github page for more.

You should be able to use `mconnectctl` to test whether a specific device is paired, e.g. for a phone called `Motorola Moto G Maciek` connected to `/org/mconnect/device/0`:

```
mconnectctl show-device /org/mconnect/device/0 | awk '/Motorola Moto G Maciek/{f=1}/Paired/{{if(f){g=1}}}f&&g{print $2;exit}'
```

This will return `true` if paired and can be used in a script.

Comment: http://manpages.org/kdeconnect-cli can also be used to show devices but real question how to find patch to folders on sd cards on that devices to later copy files from it